# Mono (monodevelop) crashes in Ubuntu when adding version-control

Tags: version-control, mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install and use monodevelop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but as soon as I install the version-control package it breaks completely.

Procedure:

Installed monodevelop

- This worked fine. I can create new projects and edit them.

Installed monodevelop-versioncontrol

- After installing this, and restarting monodevelop, it's broken:
  When I right-click on a solution or project (in the left view), 
  monodevelop crashes.

Here's the error:

```
Error while updating status of command:
MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.Commands.SwitchToBranch

Details:
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepositoryReference  
(System.String path, System.String id) [0x00000] in  
<filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepository (IWorkspaceObject 
entry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitCommandHandler.get_Repository () [0x00000] in 
<filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.SwitchToBranchHandler.Update 
(MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandArrayInfo info) [0x00000] in 
<filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.InternalUpdate 
(MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandArrayInfo info) [0x00000] 
in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DefaultUpdateCommandInfo 
(MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.ActionCommand cmd, 
MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandInfo info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommandInfo (System.Object 
commandId, 
MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandTargetRoute targetRoute) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0
```

After this, monodevelop is 100% unresponsive, and it has to be killed manually.

The same - more or less - happens if I just left-click on the top meny entry "Version Control", or through the right-click menu - except there are several slightly different error messages:

```
Error while updating status of command:
MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.Commands.UpdateSolution

Error while updating status of command:
MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.Commands.SolutionStatus

....
```

- And a bunch of other quite similar errors. If I click them all out, monodevelop becomes responsive again. But it's completely unusable.

Anyone got any ideas?

During an early attempt, I installed monodevelop, monodevelop-versionctrol and the TFS add-in. Back then, it didn't crash. However, it crashed when I tried checking out a visualstudio.com project, and entered the wrong information. After that, the problems have been permanent. Even though I've removed every visible trace of everything on the system.

This happens with existing and new solutions/projects created after the version-control package is installed. I've also completely uninstalled, and manually removed, all mono files I can find on the system, and reinstalled everything. I've done this two times, so I'm not wasting more time on that.

UPDATE:

I fixed the first error - the crash when right-clicking the solution or project - by disabling Git under Add-ins -> Version Control. However, it still creates errors when clicking "Version-Contron" in the top  menu, or through the right-click menu.

NOTE: If I start monodevelop and don't open a solution, it doesn't crash when clicking the "Version-Control" menu.

UPDATE 2:

And, of course, if I disable "Team Foundation Server" in the Add-ins, the crashes are all gone.

So, for some reason, monodevelop crashes if I have ANY version control add-ins enabled. That narrows down the problem, of course, but still makes monodevelop unusable.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the TFS add-in, of course. The second I enable it, the error/crash happens when I click the "Version Control menu".

UPDATE 3:

ANOTHER complete removal and cleaning, and then reinstall of monodevelop and monodevelop-versioncontrol:

- Git, Subversion and TFS plugins are already installed and enabled by the default installation, even though I haven't added the correct repository.
- The second I click the "Team" top menu, with no solution/project loaded (clean installation), the errors start tumbling in.

CONCLUSION:

Mono for Linux - at least Ubuntu - is so broken as to be absolutely useless and unusable. My advice is to stay away. From what I can see from other poor souls on the web, who have been fooled into thinking this is a real, professional piece of software, it's not much better for Windows. No reason at all to use anything but VisualStudio and .NET.

Comment: So, to recap: If Git is enabled in the add-ins, right-clicking the project/solution name crashes monodevelop completely. If TFS is enabled (same place), it creates a bunch of errors, and there is no TFS/version control functionality available (everything's greyed out). Not sure about subversion, but I really don't care either.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclusion. What is described here is a Ubuntu 14.04 packaging issue, not a monodevelop itself. I use monodevelop compiled from sources in Ubuntu and version control works fine. You should post the bug in the launchpad site and the Ubuntu maintainers will fix it. The way to resolve your issue just now without waiting the maintainers - compile monodevelop from the sources and use it.

Comment: Thanks. In part, I agree with you. However, compiling from source is not an option, since experience has taught me to keep a 100% clean apt system.

Comment: Monodevelop can be run without installation with `make run` command or it can be installed to the alternative prefix without affecting the curently installed packages, or it can be installed with `make checkinstall` command, which performs package installation or it can be installed from the alternative deb sources created by the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to answer my own question here:

This simply doesn't work, and there's no solution for it. After trying absolutely everything and then some, I actually REINSTALLED Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Then I installed monodevelop and monodevelop-versioncontrol. The exact same errors occur.

monodevelop with version control doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04, period.

Comment: It seems like even the *standard* Mono doesn't like Ubuntu 14.04LTS, discovered this when installing a gameserver control panel (TCAdmin) on my main server which requires Mono. Installed Mono, rebooted, server wouldn't boot and found out it was due to Mono crashing.